# How can I modify standard search query to include also ACF custom fields values?

Tags: wp-query, query, search, advanced-custom-fields, meta-query

I have to check if word the user is looking for is  also contained in a ACF custom fields. So I modify the standard query to search also into meta_query field I need:

```
function modifica_search( $query ) {
if ( $query->is_search() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    $meta_query = array(
        array(
            'key' => 'contenuto',
            'value' => sanitize_text_field( $_GET['s']),
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    );

    $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
}
} 
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'modifica_search' );
```

but printng out the query (for *?s=milano*)I notice that there is an AND operator (the bold one) where I need an OR :

... WHERE 1=1  AND (((nctm_posts.post_title LIKE '%milano%') OR (nctm_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '%milano%') OR (nctm_posts.post_content LIKE '%milano%')))  **AND** (( nctm_postmeta.meta_key = 'contenuto' AND nctm_postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%milano%' ) ...

how can I solve this?

Comment: Look also this plugin: [ACF: Better Search](https://wordpress.org/plugins/acf-better-search/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm typically against using a bunch of plugins, but an option for you is to use the [Relevanssi](https://wordpress.org/plugins/relevanssi/) plugin. I use it along side ACF and allows you to search within those fields.

If you decide to use it, after installation/activation, go to the setting page for the plugin and scroll down to the "Indexing Options" section and under that there is a field called, "Custom fields to index". You have a few options. Here's the description from the plugin itself:

> A comma-separated list of custom fields to include in the index. Set to 'visible' to index all visible custom fields and to 'all' to index all custom fields, also those starting with a '_' character.

I typically set it to "visible" so it'll search all of my visible custom fields.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in the end I preferred to use a custom query
`global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results("
SELECT ... `